# Duplicate classes wildfly maven plugin

Tags: maven, wildfly, wildfly-maven-plugin

I am using the wildfly-maven-plugin version 1.0.2.Final.  When I run `mvn install wildfly:deploy` I get compilation errors for duplicate classes.  These errors do not occur when I run the build without deploying.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part(s) of the build output to your question.

Comment: Also adding your pom.xml would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my gradle build duplicate classes error (hamcrest-core) with this gradle codes :`implementation ('junit:junit:4.12'){
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module:'hamcrest-core'
    }`

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was running this command:

```
mvn clean install wildfly:deploy
```

I read the documentation and learned that wildfly:deploy invokes the *package* goal.

[wildfly:deploy documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html)

So I tried this command:

```
mvn clean wildfly:deploy
```

...and it deployed my war with no duplicate class errors.

The classes which originally were being duplicated are generated as a package from an external library.  My guess is this package was being generated a second time when wildfly:deploy is called.